# Can someone reset my iPad without knowing the PIN or having the "Find My iPhone" account access?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icloud, find-my-iphone

Just a hypothetical question. I'm using an iPad Air with a PIN to unlock it and a `Find My iPhone` set up on it. If I lost it, can someone simply reset it and start using it like if it was a new iPad without knowing the PIN or having access to my iCloud account?

PS. I see [videos like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJanCW0goks), as well as many posts on this site, claiming that if put the iPad in the DFU-Mode it can be reset. So what's the point of setting up the `Find My iPhone` feature then?